# UIGestureRecognizer strange behavior for single tap

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I want to be able to detect double that and also when the finger touches the layer. It is not exactly single tap, because for a tap to occur the finger has to touch and leave the screen. I want to detect the exact moment one or more fingers touch on a view.

This is the code I have:

```
    doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                  initWithTarget:self 
                  action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    [doubleTap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [doubleTap setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];


    singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                 initWithTarget:self
                 action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [singleTap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTap];
    [singleTap setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

this is how I handle the single tap

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self doSomething];
    }
}
```

this code just triggers handleSingleTap method when the finger leaves, so the state there is always UIGestureRecognizerStateEnd.

How do I trigger that for the moment one or more fingers touch the view but the fingers are still there?

thanks.

Comment: If your view is a `UIView`, you could simply use `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:` to detect when the fingers are still there

Comment: Use long press gesture recognizer with minimumPressDuration = 0.001

Comment: @Mavericks - I think you may have a point here. I will check that out.\

Comment: @Mavericks - SIMPLY P E R F E C T! So simple and I did not see that! damn! THANKS! Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept and give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use long press gesture recognizer with minimumPressDuration = 0.001 .